# How to change a global variable by a function1 and use the value of this global variable retruned by function1 in a function 2

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a beginner in jQuery, and I'm confronted with a problem.

I have created a global variable that is used by a function and I try to make the function modify the global variable so that I can use it in the second function.

When I run the script runs, function 2 called `textMyFunction` in the code returns:

> Scroll Value :undefined

Can you help me please? Sorry about my English

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            var scrollValue;
            var multiply;

           function rescue()
           {
                $(document).scroll(function()
                {
                    scrollValue =  $(this).scrollTop(); // Problem at the line
                    $('#border1').text('Scroll Value :' + scrollValue);
                    $('#border2').text('Scroll Value :' + scrollValue);
                    $('#border3').text('Scroll Value :' + scrollValue);

                    if(scrollValue > 141)
                    {
                        //$('.divanimate').css('width',scrollValue*3);
                        $('.divanimate').css('top',scrollValue*3/5);
                    }   
                });
           }

           rescue();

           function textMyfunction()
           {
              $('#border4').text('Scroll Value :' + scrollValue);
           }

           textMyfunction();
});
```

Comment: Because when you call to `textMyfunction` the `$(document).scroll` didn't invoke yet so `scrollValue` is `undefined`..

Comment: A side note, are you sure that listening to `scroll` on the `document` (but not on the `window`) - See that example: https://api.jquery.com/scroll/#entry-examples